# Copy 'n' th character from textbox1 to textbox2; n is the click count of button

Tags: vb.net

Am on developing a game using vb.net, for that i need to implement the following algorithm.
   Algorithm: I have **two text-boxes**, text1 and text2 and a **button**. text2 is **empty** and text1 having some **static values**
   when i click on the button first time the first letter is copied to text2
   when i click again then first two letters are copied to text2 and so on.
   the click count number of characters are copied to text2 from one.

ie.,

```
Text1.Text = "sample text"
Text2.text = ""
dim cnt as integer=0

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  cnt += 1
  ' here how can i take single characters from text1? and place it in text2 based on cnt
End sub
```

Comment: ASP.NET ***MVC*** doesn't have things like click events on buttons: it handles HTTP requests with a response. Have you selected the right tag for the kind of application you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 dim cliks as Integer  = 0  ' initialize an integer variable
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
 clicks += 1 ' in each click increment the value of the variable  by 1(click count)
 TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, clicks)' take sub string of the text1 from 0 to click count 
 End Sub
```

Comment: @  Philip : see my updations in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a HiddenField to count your number of clic.

```
  Text1.Text = "sample text";
    Char[] listLetters = Text1.Text.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenCountClic; i++)
    {
        Text2.text += listLetters[i].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim cnt as integer=0
Dim text1 As String =Text1.text

If text.Length > cnt Then
    Text2.text = (Text1.Text).Substring(0, cnt)
    cnt++
End If
```

Declare "cnt" as  static or global variable so that it retain the value.